# UEFI SSD hidden from Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, bios, grub, uefi

I have a HP Prodesk 600 G3, and I were able to install Fedora 28 on the nvme SSD. When I put the computer in BIOS mode, then I wasn't able to see the UEFI Fedora SSD anymore from the BIOS or from a booted USB stick.

When I restored the BIOS to factory defaults, ie UEFI mode, then I could see the fedora SSD again from UEFI, but I can't see the device when I boot from an USB stick.

When in UEFI mode, I can start Grub, and with `ls` see the 3 GPT partitions.

**Problem**

Since the Fedora is somehow broken, I can't boot it up. Not even in single user mode.

When in UEFI mode I can't see the fedora SSD from a booted USB stick.

When in BIOS mode, the Fedora SSD is gone from both the BIOS and a booted USB stick.

**Question**

I am guessing if I were able to erase the Fedora SSD with all zeroes, then I would be able to see the SSD again from BIOS mode.

Could TPM somehow play a role in this?

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The important part is, that it is an NVME SSD: It needs driver support to be seen by the OS and the firmware. Your firmware obviously doesn't have the necessary bits baked into BIOS, but it does have in UEFI (This is quite normal: NVME wasn't invented, when BIOS was the standard firmware model).

If you boot with a USB stick, you might need to load those drivers manually - they are quite often not part of a standard rescue image. Try `modprobe nvme` on any modern distro (Ubuntu Bionic Server is known to work).

I had to overcome a similar problem: One of the servers I am responsible for wouldn't boot from NVME at all, the only solution was to put `/boot` on a tiny slice of one of the SAS disks.

Comment: When Fedora fails to startup it goes into Dracut. If I do `bash` `ls /dev` I would have expected to see the nvme device, but I don't. How can I boot to Dracut and it doesn't have an nvme device? This is in UEFI mode.

Comment: `modprobe nvme` from Dracut doesn't give me the device either...

Comment: Bonus question. When in UEFI mode, and boot from an USB stick. How come I can't see the nvme SSD? The first time I installed Fedora I were able to. `modprobe nvme` doesn't give me the device either here...

Comment: I am not familiar with the dracut mechanism (Debian-based shop here), but there must be a way to include a module. Maybe it's as easy as adding nvme to /etc/modules ?

Comment: To your first question: Since UEFI has boot support for NVME, it can load your boot loader and start - but since your boot configuration does not have NVME support built into it, it can't mount the root fs.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, when changed the boot mode to UEFI and SSD was not visible from Linux (Arch).  Then I enabled **Enabled Attempt Legacy Boot** from BIOS and then it detected.
[image]